# WAMP server Access Denied

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have tried all the options and answers available on this site for problem. the problem is i have installed "Wamp Server 2.2" and when i open 'PHPmyadmin' page it shows the following error message:

```
MySQL said:
#1045-Access denied for user 'root'@'local-host' (using password: NO)
```

I tried reinstalling server, restarting server and also I tried resetting the password also and done everything that i could find here as a solution. but it doesn't worked. please help me fix this.

Comment: This could be an issue with phpmyadmin, Have you looked at your mysql.ini files, that is where that data is kept.

Comment: You have set an Password of the MySql server. And, you are logging with empty password. Goto the PhpMyAdmin Folder, there is Configuration file, open and change the Valid MySql password and try again.

Comment: i have not set any password. finally i m able to open it. thank you guys;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit config.inc.php file.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'YOUR_USERNAME';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'YOUR_PASSWORD';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Comment: I have tried this only and it worked. thanks a lot. you have saved me.

Comment: After that i needed to erase all my cookies of the browser.